# apache geode disk-store are not repopulating on cluster restart

Tags: geode

I run a geode cluster with various regions backed up to a disk-store specified in a cache.xml like this:

`<region name="deal" refid="REPLICATE_PERSISTENT"><region-attributes disk-store-name="deal" disk-synchronous="false"></region-attributes></region>`

I think the disk-store are recording the data in the region, but when I stop and start the geode, the regions aren't repopulating with the stored data, which I was expecting. Is there a way to do that?

When I restart, in Pulse I see the empty regions (ignore the heartbeats in the 3 regions) all in the lower rhs as below:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening here, persistent regions (either `REPLICATE` or `PARTITION`) should recover the data from disk when they start up again... maybe the issue is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710697/for-an-apache-geode-3-server-cluster-with-use-cluster-configuration-true-the-rep) other post and the fact that some servers don't have the regions created on them?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault by clearing down the disk stores to try and answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710697/for-an-apache-geode-3-server-cluster-with-use-cluster-configuration-true-the-rep). Once I realised and restored the disk stores from backup they worked as expected:

[image: disk stores pulse]